# Scala: declaring val within for loop, if condition

Tags: scala

I'm a scala beginner and trying to understand how val works in Scala. I read that vals cannot be modified. When I do the following:

```
for( line <- Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines() ) {
   val currentLine = line
   println(currentLine)
}
```

currentLine is updated in each iteration, while I expect it to be initialized with the first line and hold it till the end, or at least give a re-initialization error of some sort. Why is this so? Is the val created and destroyed in each iteration? My second question: I would like to use x outside if in the following code.

```
if( some condition is satisfied) val x = 2 else val x = 3
```

As of now, I'm getting an "Illegal start of simple expression" error. Is there a way to use x outside if?

Comment: To be clear, the difference between `val` and `var` is that a `val` cannot be reassigned.

Comment: Remember that `val currentLine = line` isn't the same as `currentLine = line` in isolation. Only the latter attempts to assign a new value to an existing value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Yes, the `val` is created and destroyed on each iteration.
2. `val x = if(condition) 2 else 3` would do what you want.

Edit: You could rewrite 2. to `if(conditon) {val x = 2} else {val x = 3}` (to make it compile) but that would do nothing, since the if does not return anything and the variable can not be used outside the `if`

Answer (score 4):

**For Loop**

You can break it down into a `map` operation.

```
for( line <- Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines() ) {
   val currentLine = line
   println(currentLine)
}
```

So this code transforms to

```
Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines().map( line => block )
```

`block` could be any expression. Where in your case `block` is:

```
{
   val currentLine = line
   println(currentLine)
}
```

Here `currentLine` is local to `block` and is created for each of the values of `line` given to `map` operation.

**If-Else**

Again following is also wrong:

```
if( some condition is satisfied) val x = 2 else val x = 3
```

Essentially `if-else` in Scala returns a value. So it should be:

```
if( condition ) expression1 else expression1
```

In your case you it can be:

```
if( condition ) { val x = 2 } else { val x = 3 }
```

However an assignment returns `Unit` ( or `void` if you want an analogy with Java / C++ ). So You can simply take the value of `if-else` like so:

```
val x = if( condition ) { 2 } else { 3 }
// OR
val x = if( condition ) 2 else 3
```

Answer (score 3):

No answer mentioned it so in addition to what was said :

1. The `val` is made available for garbage collection on each iteration (and thus is not accessible from the next loop iteration). This is due to what is called `scope of variables` which is limited to the block in scala (same as Java).
2. As stated by @Kigyo `val x = if(condition) 2 else 3` would do what you want, because you do only one assignation. If you put the assignation to val into the blocks, then the scope of this val is the block and thus not usable like you want to.

Comment: Regarding (1): If only that were true! The compiler doesn't replace reference locals with `null` when execution leaves their scope. That can occasionally cause memory-leak-like symptoms.

Comment: Ok so maybe I should rephrase it : the val is normally destroyed on each iteration  ?

Comment: Not so much "destroyed" as "made available for garbage collection"

Comment: @KevinWright: That's the point, it's *not* nulled-out so it's not available for GC until the method returns. The place where it's most likely to bite you is in non-tail-recursive methods.

Comment: @RandallSchulz I was making more of a general comment on what "destroyed" typically means for objects on the JVM

Answer (score 1):

1st question: yes, in every iteration a new val is created

2nd question:  you could rewrite it is

```
 val x =  if (some condition is satisfied)
  2
 else
  3
```